# How do I fix change appium Android settings

Tags: android, appium

I receive Failed to install Shared Library with appium 1.3.1 I am using Android emulators both Google and generic. The Main activity is not correct I want to change this setting to hopefully get my appium install to work. It keeps showing the wrong ones in the drop-down how can I change this?

Comment: please share your code. hard to say anything just looking at your question

Comment: No Code just trying to run for first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install Appium latest versions Because some of the major changes will affect only latest version builds

Refer the link:
[Appium latest versions](https://appium.io/downloads)